# for loop iterate tuples

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, tuples

I'm a beginner in Python (and going back to coding after 20 years...)

I'm doing a small script in order to learn irregular english verbs. 
I create my dict which look like this (it's in french)

```
verbes = {
"abide":["abode","abode","respecter / se conformer à"],
"arise":["arisen","arisen","survenir"],
}
```

if i want to iterate the verbes i'm doing that for exemple:

```
for verb, (pret, past, trad) in verbes.items():
    print "Le verbe %s se conjugue au prétérit par %s, au participe passé par %s et se traduit par %s" % (verb, pret, past, trad)
```

Ok that works. 
Then i found out i can import random to pick up one random key and value in my dictionnary

```
rand = random.choice(verbes.items())
```

If i print rand i have a key, value
but if i iterate again i have a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\exverbe1.py", line 209, in <module>
    for verb, (pret, past, trad) in rand.items(): AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I'm not yet at the "tuple" lesson but i've tried to turn it into a list, a dict, etc. without success. I looked over "for loop tuple" in stackoverflow without result. So now i'm asking for help after 3 hours trying to figure it out...
Thanks

Comment: `random.choice(verbes.items())` gives you a tuple `(key, value)`, **not** a dictionary. Tuples, as the error message states, don't have the `items` attribute.

Comment: You can assign it directly or indirectly: `verb, (pret, past, trad) = random.choice(verbes.items()) or some_var_which_holds_keyval_tuple`

Comment: .items returns a list of tuples which are  key/value pairs, random.choice picks one of those tuples so you have a two element tuple not a dict.

Comment: What's your desired output by the way?

Comment: Well i would like then to print randomly the verb or the preterit or past or translation and user would have to write down the past, verb preterit if "translation" showed up, or past, preterit translation if "verb" showed up, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`random.choice(verbes.items())` picks one tuple at random from `verbes.items()`. `rand` therefore contains one item - `rand[0]` holds the key and `rand[1]` the value.

If what you're trying to do is iterate over the items in the value list:

```
for val in rand[1]:
  print val
```

To unpack the `rand` tuple into its constituents:

```
verb, (pret, past, trad)
```

`verb` now contains the key, and `pret`, `past` and `trad` each element in the list corresponding to the key.

Answer (score 1):

`rand` is an item from from `verbes` so no need to call items again:

```
rand = random.choice(verbes.items())
verb, (pret, past, trad) = rand
```

`dict.items()` returns a list of the "items" in the dict. Each item is a tuple of the form `(key, value)`. `random.choice` returns one of those tuples. I see that you're trying to loop over `rand`, maybe you want more than one random item? If so you can do something like:

```
for i in range(N):
     verb, (pret, past, trad) = random.choice(verbes.items())
     # Do more stuff
```

Update

In python they call asigment such as `a, b = iterable` unpacking. You can use many different types on the right hand side, for example:

```
# A tuple
a, b = ("A", "B")
# A list
a, b = ["A", "B"]
# A string
a, b = "AB"
```

In the simple case, the number or variables needs to be same same as the number of items in the iterable or python will raise an error. You can nest unpacking so:

```
 a, (b, c, d) = ("A", "BCD")
 # is the same as
 a, temp = ("A", "BCD")
 (b, c, d) = temp
```

The `()` on the outside are optional so `a, b = item` is the same as `(a, b) = item`.

Python 3 introduces even more advanced types of unpacking that I never use, but you can read about them [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

Comment: Ok thanks that works. but i don't understand this part `verb, (pret, past, trad) = rand` how do you assign all of this in one variable ?

Comment: @rEkOM I've added a basic explanation of python's unpacking rules.